# IntelliJ center next occurrence

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ when searching for text (Control-F), F3 moves to the next occurrence. Unfortunately when it finds the next occurrence, it doesn't vertically center the text. ie, it scrolls the editor such that the next occurrence is at the **bottom** of the screen. What I want is for it to scroll such that the next occurrence is centered vertically (like Eclipse and vim does).

I'm running IntelliJ 10.5.1 on OS X 10.6.

**Follow-up**: I have `Prefer scrolling editor canvas to keep caret line centered` enabled. In some instances it centers, other times it does not. The above setting doesn't seem to impact this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings` > `IDE Settings` > `Editor`

Choose `Prefer scrolling editor canvas to keep caret line centered`

Comment: I already have "Prefer scrolling editor canvas to keep caret line centered" enabled but it still sometimes doesn't center.

Comment: I'm using 10.5.4 now and haven't seen the buggy behavior since.